# Converting an array of ints to titlesForSegmentAtIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom segmented control that you can select multiple segments and saves the selected indexes selected in to an array. What I want to do is for each int I want to get the titleForSegmentAtIndex and put the titles into an array or string, but am struggling to set up the correct loop.

Here is what I have right now:

```
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

prints:

```
(
    0,
    1,
    4
)
```

Here is my array:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[self.type.selectedSegmentIndexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [array addObject:@(idx)];
}];
```

And I assume I need to use `[segmentControl titleForSegmentAtIndex:int]`
but dont know how to incorporate it into a loop.

Comment: You cannot have ints in an NSArray, you can only have NSNumbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `NSMutableArray` and add the titles in a `for ... in` loop.

```
NSMutableArray *titles = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSNumber *index in array) {
    [titles addObject:[segmentedControl titleForSegmentAtIndex:index.integerValue]];
}
```

You can also use a plain old `for` loop, but the `for ... in` is cleaner and faster.

Comment: I get Expected ';' in 'for' statement specifier when I do this. and do I have to define int in this example?

Comment: @BluGeni Actually, that won't work either... What type are the indexes stored in the array? It's impossible to store integers in an ```NSArray```, so they can't be ```int```'s.

Comment: NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self.type.selectedSegmentIndexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [array addObject:@(idx)];

Comment: @BluGeni Ah, try now. They're ```NSNumber```'s, not ```int```'s.

Comment: @BluGeni Great, not a problem.